# Ubuntu Purge Kernel Cron

Tags: linux, cron, kernel

I have a purge kernel script which works fine if manually run. When I run this with a cron it works to a point and then stops...

The script is purge-old-kernels.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
dpkg -l linux-* | awk '/^ii/{ print $2}' | grep -v -e `uname -r | cut -f1,2 -d"-"` | grep -e [0-9] | grep -E "(image|headers)" | xargs apt-get -y purge |  logger -i -t purge-kernel
echo "Finished purge of unused kernel images" |  logger -i -t purge-kernel
```

The Cronjob is setup as such

```
35 09 * * * bash /opt/purge-old-kernels.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

When the cron runs I get the following syslog output

> May 23 09:46:01 devser1 CRON[6552]: (root) CMD (bash
>   /opt/purge-old-kernels.sh >/dev/null 2>&1)
>
> May 23 09:46:01 devser1 purge-kernel[6562]: Reading package lists...
>
> May 23 09:46:01 devser1 purge-kernel[6562]: Building dependency
>   tree...
>
> May 23 09:46:01 devser1 purge-kernel[6562]: Reading state
>   information...
>
> May 23 09:46:02 devser1 purge-kernel[6562]: The following packages
>   will be  REMOVED
>
> May 23 09:46:02 devser1 purge-kernel[6562]:   linux-headers-4.4.0-116*
>   linux-headers-4.4.0-116-generic*
>
> May 23 09:46:02 devser1 purge-kernel[6562]:   linux-headers-4.4.0-119*
>   linux-headers-4.4.0-119-generic*
>
> May 23 09:46:02 devser1 purge-kernel[6562]:   linux-headers-4.4.0-121*
>   linux-headers-4.4.0-121-generic*
>
> May 23 09:46:02 devser1 purge-kernel[6562]:
>   linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic* linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic*
>
> May 23 09:46:02 devser1 purge-kernel[6562]:
>   linux-image-4.4.0-121-generic* linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic*
>
> May 23 09:46:02 devser1 purge-kernel[6562]:
>   linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic*
>   linux-image-extra-4.4.0-121-generic*
>
> May 23 09:46:02 devser1 purge-kernel[6562]: 0 to upgrade, 0 to newly
>   install, 12 to remove and 32 not to upgrade.
>
> May 23 09:46:02 devser1 purge-kernel[6562]: After this operation, 918
>   MB disk space will be freed.
>
> May 23 09:46:02 devser1 purge-kernel[6580]: Finished purge of unused
>   kernel images

What would cause this job to stop at the point it would then start to purge the kernels?

Answer (score 0):

Add`PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`